# Limitar memória SQL Server por usuário

Tags: sql-server

Gostaria de saber se é possível limitar o uso de memória e limitar o tempo da query do SQL Server por usuários:

- Bloquear o tempo de execução da query por usuário.
- Bloquear a memória utilizada na consulta por usuário.

O motivo:

Alguns usuários realizam consultas que demoram muito por mal escrita de códigos e utilização de scripts sem conhecimentos ou domínios.

Comment: Da uma olhada nisso aqui. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx

Comment: Vou pesquisar sobre o assunto.

Muito obrigado.

Comment: certo, boa sorte e bons estudos